# Download a non html file with HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm writing a JUnit test that involves the downloading of a file from the web app. How do I do that with HtmlUnit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't what kind of file, but maybe code for [this](https://htmlunit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/htmlunit/trunk/htmlunit/src/test/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/attachment/AttachmentTest.java) test might be helpful. If not try to find answers in other tests.

Comment: could you please look at the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131049/problem-in-htmlunit-api-for-java-headless-browser

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet you already solved the problem, but since this question is on google's top results when searching for "htmlunit download", here's the standard solution. `downloadLink` is the element with the link to the file you intend to download (a button, an input, an anchor...)

```
try {
    InputStream is = downloadLink.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
    try {
        File f = new File("filename.extension");
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024]; // make it bigger if you want. Some recommend 8x, others 100x
        while (read = is.read(bytes)) {
            os.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        os.close();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Exception handling
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // Exception handling
}
```